# URL and DOI are in a different font within Literature Cited

Tags: bibliographies

I created a custom bibliographystyle using `latex makebst` for a journal, and it is mostly right. Unfortunately the DOI and URL to webpages are both in a different font than the rest of the bibliography entry, and the URL will run off the page rather than wrapping to the next line.

the relevant portion of my bst:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{
  doi empty$
    { url }
    { "http://dx.doi.org/" doi * }
  if$
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\urlprefix\url{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

What do I need to change to have the output in the same font as the rest of my reference?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font face that's used when the argument of an `\url` or `\doi` instruction is typeset usually does not dependon the bst file. Assuming that the [url](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package is loaded, the font face is determined by the argument of the `\urlstyle` macro, which (along with `\url` macro itself) is provided by the `url` package. (The `xurl` package also loads `url` package.)

Lets review Section 3, "Style", of the [url](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package -- yes, the entire section consists of a single, six-line paragraph (highlights added):

[image]

Many document classes and citation management package either take the system default font face, which is `tt`, or execute something like `\urlstyle{same}`. If you don't like the monospaced font default, feel free to run `\urlstyle{same}` or `\urlstyle{rm}`.

If the url package is *not* loaded, the bst file has to provide a dummy or placeholder definition of `\url`, which -- as you've observed -- is not very smart as it doesn't allow for line breaks in the typeset URL string.

You also wrote:

> and the URL will run off the page rather than wrapping to the next line

This only happens if you don't load the [url](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) (or [xurl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xurl), or [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)) package. I suggest you run `\usepackage{xurl}` in your document.

Finally, you asked,

> What do I need to change to have the output in the same font as the rest of my reference?

In addition to loading the `xurl` package, I'd recommend you run `\urlstyle{same}`.

Comment: Excellent, that fixed everything perfectly. Thank you.